# Why does this count as a memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I was searching memory leaks in my app using Instruments and found this:
[image]
Why does it count as memory leak? Shouldn't this be released the next time autorelease pool is drained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take is that the release on the last line is the release corresponding to the autorelease. The fact that there is still a retain left supports this. If all retains are balanced the final line would be a release with a RefCt of 0.